# what does "//[[:blank:]]/" do here?

Tags: bash, sh

I could not understand shell script in this context. Please help.

```
inDumpPort=1
var=${inDumpPort//[[:blank:]]/}
```

output is still 1.
Why(or how) it is needed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[:blank:]]` matches a space or tab space.

It is actually removing all spaces from `$inDumpPort` variable.

It will be more clear with this example:

```
inDumpPort="   1 "
echo "<$inDumpPort>"
<   1 >

echo "<${inDumpPort//[[:blank:]]/}>"
<1>
```

Answer (score 1):

How anubhava already mentioned, the expression is removing all the appearances of the character class that you give in the squared brackets. because your bash character class is :blank:, it removes the blanks in the variable.

If you do this:

```
inDumpPort="Hello World"
echo "<${inDumpPort//[[:lower:]]/}>"
<H W>
```

It will remove all the lowercase characters from the variable `inDumpPort`.

Look here for more Bash Character classes: [Bash Character Classes](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_03.html)

Comment: The primary feature at issue is **substring replacement**. Regardless of whether you use **character classes** or simple **pattern matching** for stuff, the code at issue is `${variable//stuff/}`. Your point is well taken, but be wary of `answering` questions with examples not called for in the question. That is generally handled in comments.

Comment: Should i delete my answer?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote either. You are still fairly new. I'm just trying to save you grief in the future. Welcome to SO.

Comment: However, your example is exactly backwards.  Your code removes uppercase but the sample output has the *lowercase* removed.